# what is wrong about "error: failed to push some refs to"

Tags: git, branch, push

I cloned a remote branch to local, 
$git clone -b my_branch REMOTE_REPO 
made some changes and then was going to push back to the remote branch. 
$git push origin master:my_branch

But the push was rejected:

```
Counting objects: 30, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (12/12), done.
Writing objects: 100% (16/16), 4.15 KiB, done.
Total 16 (delta 8), reused 7 (delta 4)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (8/8)
remote: Processing changes: done
To ssh://user@gerrit.foo.net:29418/foo.git
 ! [remote rejected] my_branch -> my_branch (non-fast forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://user@gerrit.foo.net:29418/foo.git'
```

So what's wrong?

Comment: Why are you trying to push your local `master` branch to the remote branch `my_branch`?  On which local branch did you commit your changes?

Answer (score 0):

Commit to your local repository before pushing to remote repositiry.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody else updated that branch in the remote repository since the time you cloned it.  You need to pull and merge those changes into your copy of the branch before you can push your changes.

Comment: I am quite sure nobody else updated that branch since the branch was created by me minutes ago and no one knew about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$git push origin master:my_branch
```

Here you are trying to push your local <strike>repo</strike> branch `master` to the remote <strike>repo</strike> branch`my_branch`.

If you want to push your local <strike>repo</strike> branch `my-branch` to remote <strike>repo</strike> branch `master`, then the command
should be `$git push origin my_branch:master`.

I think that's what you are tyring to do..